# Session variable can't be access to different page

Tags: php, session

I have a problem on getting the session variables to work on different pages

I have three php scripts
1. index.php (includes a html form)

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$_SESSION['billTo_email'] = $_POST['billTo_email'];

}
?>
<form id = 'form_submit'  method="post" action = "NetworkOnline.php">
<td><input type="text" name="billTo_email" id="f_name2" /></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
</form>
?>
```

2. NetworkOnline.php

   ```
     <?php
     session_start();
     $_SESSION['billTo_email'] = $_POST["billTo_email"];
     ?> 

     $f_name=$_POST["f_name"];
     $l_name=$_POST["l_name"];
     $billTo_country=$_POST["billTo_country"];
     $billTo_city=$_POST["billTo_city"];
     $billTo_state=$_POST["billTo_state"];
     $billTo_street1=$_POST["billTo_street1"];
     $billTo_pin=$_POST["billTo_pin"];
     $billTo_email  = $_SESSION["billTo_email"];
   ```
3. response.php

   ```
   <?php
   session_start();
   $_SESSION["billTo_email"] = $_POST["billTo_email"];
   ?>

   <form name = "form1" method = "post" action="mail.php" >
   <input type="hidden" name="order" id="order" value="<?php echo $order ?>" >
   <input type="hidden" name="bank" id="bank" value="<?php echo $bank ?>" >
   <input type="hidden" name="amount" id="amount" value="<?php echo $amount ?>" >
   <input type = "test" name= "email" id ="email" value= "<?php echo $billTo_email ?>">
   <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
   </form>
   ```

Comment: Your closing tag on NetworkOnline.php is in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
index.php:

```
<html>
<form id = 'form_submit'  method="post" action = "NetworkOnline.php">
<td><input type="text" name="billTo_email" /></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
</form>
</html>
```

NetworkOnline.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['billTo_email'] = $_POST["billTo_email"];
header('Location: response.php');
?>
```

response.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$billTo_email=$_SESSION["billTo_email"] 
?>
<form name = "form1" method = "post" action="mail.php" >
<br />
<br />
<input type = "test" name= "email"  value= "<?php echo $billTo_email ?>">
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but its still not working on this.

Answer (score -1):

Try below,

Your closing tags are wrong in place,

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$_SESSION['billTo_email'] = $_POST['billTo_email'];
}
?>
<form id = 'form_submit'  method="post" action = "NetworkOnline.php">
<td><input type="text" name="billTo_email" id="f_name2" /></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
</form>
```

**NetworkOnline.php**

```
  <?php
  session_start();

  $_SESSION['billTo_email'] = $_POST["billTo_email"];
  $f_name=$_POST["f_name"];
  $l_name=$_POST["l_name"];
  $billTo_country=$_POST["billTo_country"];
  $billTo_city=$_POST["billTo_city"];
  $billTo_state=$_POST["billTo_state"];
  $billTo_street1=$_POST["billTo_street1"];
  $billTo_pin=$_POST["billTo_pin"];
  $billTo_email  = $_SESSION["billTo_email"];
  ?>
```

**response.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["billTo_email"] = $_POST["billTo_email"];
?>

<form name = "form1" method = "post" action="mail.php" >
<input type="hidden" name="order" id="order" value="<?php echo $order; ?>" >
<input type="hidden" name="bank" id="bank" value="<?php echo $bank; ?>" >
<input type="hidden" name="amount" id="amount" value="<?php echo $amount; ?>" >
<input type = "test" name= "email" id ="email" value= "<?php echo $billTo_email; ?>">
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: There is no need to check **if (isset($_POST['submit']))** as i mention in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE:**

your **index.php**

```
<form id = 'form_submit'  method="post" action = "NetworkOnline.php">
  <td><input type="text" name="billTo_email" id="f_name2" /></td>
  <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
</form>
```

**NOTE:** NO need to check `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { ... }` here, because **index.php** send data to **NetworkOnline.php**.

Your **NetworkOnline.php**:

```
<?php
  ob_start();   // turn on output buffering
  session_start();
  if( isset( $_POST['billTo_email'] ) ) { // work only if **billTo_email** has some value
     $_SESSION['billTo_email'] = $_POST["billTo_email"];
  }

  //  ?> <-- remove this closing tag

  $f_name=$_POST["f_name"]; // this line of code shows undefined variable, 
         //because in your index.php there is no any f_name field presnet.

  // your remaining codes


 ?>
```

Comment: Undefined index: f_name

Comment: I clearly mention **if()** condition above to check variables having values. And I put that two lines of code , just to show coder **misplaced** the closing tag. @jlocker

Comment: No you haven't mention that...I don't think a beginner would understand that.

Comment: Thanks SHAZ for the answer but still having difficulties of getting the data to appear on the text box of response.php

Comment: @RomeoTorreno, what difficulties you face? Can you please mention what issue you have.

Comment: Hi SHAZ is it possible to send the submitted inputs to two scripts such as Networkonline.php and response.php i just want to get the email in order for my mail function to work